# window.referrer is always empty in react SPA

Tags: reactjs, http, single-page-application, referrer

I am developing a single page react application.

I want to render different stuff depending on whether the component was opened from inside the application or from an external shared link.

I used document.referrer but it always return empty string but after a while it starts working but then I open the app in new window and it starts returning empty again.

Why document.referrer is showing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why this is happening. There is no referrer for the first load of a website through address bar and there is no referrer for it because there is no link followed throughout the application as it is SPA so the referrer stays empty.

Now if I open my app in new tab from a link in already opened same app then the referrer is my own app as the app itself opened it.

Now only to figure out how to have the referrer as itself for the first load of application as other links also send empty referrer so I cant determine if my own app is the referrer by checking for empty referrer and also my app is http and https references gets cleared up too.